# Android startBluetoothSco() not interrupted by incoming call

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've managed to get text-to-speech audio streaming through my SCO headset using **startBluetoothSco()**, but it's not interrupted by incoming phone calls, as documented at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html:

> Note that the phone application always has the priority on the usage of the SCO connection for telephony. If this method is called while the phone is in call it will be ignored. Similarly, if a call is received or sent while an application is using the SCO connection, the connection will be lost for the application and NOT returned automatically when the call ends.

When a call comes in, I can hear both the phone call audio and my text-to-speech audio at the same time.  Has anyone successfully gotten the correct behavior with incoming phone calls?  I'm testing on a Samsung Captivate running Android 2.2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What stream are you using? Make sure you are not using VOICE_CALL stream.

Comment: It's using VOICE_CALL, but isn't that required to route audio to the SCO headset?  Or is there a different stream I should be using?  BTW it's going through the TextToSpeech class **speak()** method, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Rob you can use it with different audio stream